# AWS on demand EC2 instances charges breakup for an hour

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, cost-management, aws-cost-explorer

I need to know if there is a way to get a break up of an Hourly charge on demand instances.

| Instance Type | Hourly rate | vCPU | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t3.xlarge | $0.1888 | 4 | 16Gb |

Lets for an instance, Hourly rate of t3.xlarge is $0.1888 and in that how much cost is for memory and cpu.

Is it possible to get the granular level charges of each and everything from an hourly rate?

Note: Here I am trying to find the cost monitoring of an eks cluster (ec2 nodes) at a namespace level without using any other opensource tools.

Comment: That level of detail is not available afaik. While AWS might price things to that level internally, they don't publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon EC2 instances are charged based on the **Instance Type**.

If you want to change CPU or RAM then you need to **choose a different Instance Type**.

There is **no charge specifically for CPU or RAM**, nor is it possible to change the amount of CPU or RAM on an instance without changing the Instance Type.